# Change Language Message Password Rules

Tags: php, laravel, translation

i would like to change the language of the messages if the password does not match the rules.

I use the following code to check a password:

```
'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Password::min(12)
            ->mixedCase()
            ->letters()
            ->numbers()
            ->symbols()
            ->uncompromised()
        ],
```

If the password does not match the rules, I get an error message, but in English. I would like to receive this in German. I have found the method in which the messages are then generated. There they are programmed statically in english. How can I change this?

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($this->data, [
        $attribute => 'string|min:'.$this->min,
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->fail($validator->messages()->all());
    }

    $value = (string) $value;

    if ($this->mixedCase && ! preg_match('/(\p{Ll}+.*\p{Lu})|(\p{Lu}+.*\p{Ll})/u', $value)) {
        $this->fail('The :attribute must contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter.');
    }

    if ($this->letters && ! preg_match('/\pL/u', $value)) {
        $this->fail('The :attribute must contain at least one letter.');
    }

    if ($this->symbols && ! preg_match('/\p{Z}|\p{S}|\p{P}/u', $value)) {
        $this->fail('The :attribute must contain at least one symbol.');
    }

    if ($this->numbers && ! preg_match('/\pN/u', $value)) {
        $this->fail('The :attribute must contain at least one number.');
    }

    if (! empty($this->messages)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->uncompromised && ! Container::getInstance()->make(UncompromisedVerifier::class)->verify([
        'value' => $value,
        'threshold' => $this->compromisedThreshold,
    ])) {
        return $this->fail(
            'The given :attribute has appeared in a data leak. Please choose a different :attribute.'
        );
    }

    return true;
}
```

When I try to change the code, PHP-Storm warns me not to do so. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Never override anything in the vendor folder. Read [this link on localizing the language](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization)

Comment: The [validation page also has a section on localization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-custom-messages-in-language-files)

Comment: @aynber these messages are not defined in validation.php in the lang folder

Comment: nobody knows???

Answer (score 1):

Simply add these strings as keys to the js object in `resources/lang/{your_language}.json` and put your translations as values, like this:

```
{
    "The :attribute must contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter." : "O campo :attribute deve conter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula e uma minúscula.",
    "The :attribute must contain at least one letter.": "O campo :attribute deve conter pelo menos uma letra",
    "The :attribute must contain at least one symbol." : "O campo :attribute deve conter pelo menos um caractere especial.",
    "The :attribute must contain at least one number." : "O campo :attribute deve conter pelo menos um número."    
}
```